# Regex help for Alphanumeric and International characters

Tags: regex

I only want to allow

- Numbers
- Letters
- Spaces
- International Letters

Anything else I want to remove.

I am using Coldfusion.  I really haven't tried much because I have never really used regex before. I am trying to remove the "bad" characters

Here is what I am doing so far:

```
<cfset theText = "Baum -$&*( 5 Steine hoch groß 3 Stück grün****">

<cfset test1 = rereplace(theText, '[\p{L}0-9 ]', ' ', 'all')>
<cfset test2 = rereplace(theText, '[^\p{L}0-9 ]', ' ', 'all')>
```

The results:

```
Original Text: Baum -$&*( 5 Steine hoch groß 3 Stück grün****
Test 1 Result: Baum -$&*( Steine hoch groß Stück grün****
Test 2 Result: 5 3
```

In the end, I wound up doing this and it seems to be giving me what I need..

```
<cfset finalFile = varData.replaceAll('[^\p{L}0-9-.: ]',' ') />
```

Comment: what do you mean by international letters?

Comment: What regex tool/language you're using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A little demonstration of effort would be nice.

Comment: I have added more detail, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but this regex sounds like it might fit your description.

```
[^\p{L}0-9 ]
```

You don't specify a language or flavor, so assuming `\p{L}` is supported, simply replace anything that matches this pattern with an empty string `""`.

Small demo: http://rubular.com/r/W4q5PFSJRg

Comment: Sorry if it was not enough detail. I am using coldfusion.  I want to find crazy characters in the title and remove them only allowing for those that I listed.

Comment: Basically I am doing something like this:  <cfset new_item_title = rereplace(ITEM_TITLE, '[^\p{L}0-9 ]', '', 'all')>

Comment: Update your question instead of posting details in comments.